# Is it normal to being able to kill a process from outside a container?

Tags: privilege-escalation, docker, container

Situation: on `user@host` a `qemu` run and stack inside a container `user@container`

Is it normal:

- to view with `ps aux | grep qemu` from `user@host` that the process run on `user@container`?
- to be able to make `sudo kill -9 pid` of the process in the container `user@container` from the host `user@host`?

Comment: It would be abnormal to be able to do that from another container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. Docker processes on Linux are sandboxed such that they can't affect the rest of the system, but the rest of the system is free to mess with them however it wants to. They are still running on the same kernel, same file system (even if they can only see a limited portion of it), etc. Docker is not a VM; the processes running within the container are running on the same OS as those outside the container.

Given that, it would be very weird if you *couldn't* list and kill contained processes (from outside the container, and assuming you have enough privileges). Just like you can list and kill Chrome sandbox processes from a normal-privilege OS shell even though the Chrome sandbox prevents those processes from doing anything, so too can you list and kill Docker contained processes from a normal-privilege shell. Processes in one container are unable to interact with those outside of it, including those in other containers, but un-contained processes have no problem reaching "into" a container.